# Superglue on plug

Tags: usb, glue

I was fixing a junky device whose charging cable fell off, And when I superglued it back on, I accidentally got some inside the connecting area (?) and it will no longer charge. What’s the best way to remove the superglue?

Comment: If it's a junky device, get a new one. Fixing this kind of thing is very likely not worth it.

Comment: Acetone usually works, but it may affect (or melt) some plastics too

Comment: @Hearth It’s $50 junky. I spent $2-3 on a screwdriver and I think another $2-3 on the superglue. I’ll get another if I need to, but if there is a way to clean the port, I’d rather do that.

Comment: @KristoferA is there a good way to clean the inside of the port? I’d assume that washing out the acetone after a minute with sink water is a bad idea.

Comment: @Doragon Use the acetone to wash it out. Acetone evaporates quickly.

Comment: You have not specified details of the connector size and where the glue was applied. Superglue may be affected by *heat* and you can try a heat source like a soldering iron, provided, that the glue is not close to plastic parts.

Comment: It’s a mini USB port. I applied the glue to the feet attaching it to the board. I guess it spread into the port itself.   I don’t have a soldering iron though. That’s why I got superglue. I had hoped it would work just as well.

Comment: Superglue is not going to restore the electrical connection. It needs to be soldered back on.

Comment: If it came off the PCB, you need to solder it on. Conductive epoxy also technically exists but really isn't worth the price or the trouble.

Comment: @DamienD I know it won’t restore the connection, but if I glue it in place wouldn’t the contact itself restore the connection? I would solder it, but I don’t have a soldering iron or solder. And I have no idea where to get one.

Comment: It won't. Maybe if you press hard on it there will be some sort of poor connection that will be immediately broken the moment you let go.

Comment: @Doragon "broken" means that there is no overlapping material.  The only way to get a reliable contact with superglue is if there are touching free contacts that are fixed/glued individually in a manner that the contact is maintained via elastic tension.  That's close to impossible without overlap and/or surplus material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to scrape it off the gold parts without damaging the gold or the plastic too much.

A wooden toothpick dipped in acetone may work well for this.

These gold parts are the contacts that are used for charging, the nickel plated parts are less important

Comment: Not just acetone: any kind of nailpolish remover will do.  But you must not get that kind of solvent on the plastic parts.

Comment: apparently isopropyl alcohol will work too, and electronics is generally immune to that sfuff.

Comment: On superglue?  Not seen that work myself, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate#Solvents_and_debonders) does not exactly sound like something as simple as isopropyl alcohol would have a chance on anything but possibly very particular formulations.

Comment: yeah, I seems I found one of the lying clickbait sites on the internet, IPA seems to have no effect, are you sure acetone free nail polish remover works?

Comment: this guy did some tests,  soaking in acetone seems to work.  NPR not so much. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_59ZzuLJcTw